# Read Kafka topic in a Spark batch job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm writing a Spark (v1.6.0) batch job which reads from a Kafka topic.
For this I can use `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils#createRDD` however,
I need to set the offsets for all the partitions and also need to store them somewhere (ZK? HDFS?) to know from where to start the next batch job.

What is the right approach to read from Kafka in a **batch** job?

I'm also thinking about writing a **streaming** job instead, which reads from `auto.offset.reset=smallest` and saves the checkpoint
to HDFS and then in the next run it starts from that.

But in this case how can I just fetch once and stop streaming *after the first batch*?

Comment: It would be better to make two separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`createRDD` is the right approach for reading a batch from kafka.

To query for info about the latest / earliest available offsets, look at `KafkaCluster.scala` methods `getLatestLeaderOffsets` and `getEarliestLeaderOffsets`.  That file was `private`, but should be `public` in the latest versions of spark.

Comment: Thanks for the answer also on the spark list! Do you mean that these methods give a guideline on how to implement my offset lookup with the appropriate store in the backend?

Comment: No, those methods are for getting the latest available offsets from kafka. See https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/TransactionalPerBatch.scala  for an example of looking up committed offsets from a store.

Comment: @CodyKoeninger The KafkaCuster type doesn't exist in the 0.10 version. Am I missing something? I want to batch process all existing records in a topic, but there's no way to retrieve the earliest and latest offsets from Kafka.

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop the newer kafka consumer api will let you seek to the beginning or end of a topic to figure out what earliest and latest offsets are, see https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: @CodyKoeninger Yeah, but with the spark stream API you'd have to first start consuming from the topic to get those offsets. There is no generic kafka consumer api. I just want to start a batch job with the min and max offsets for each partition, not stream data. Are you saying I should just pull in the kafka consumer artifact? It wasn't necessary with the spark streaming 0.8 client, but lack of the KafkaCluster class in 0.10 makes something else necessary.

Comment: Don't add Kafka consumer artifact, it's already included as a transitive dependency. Just use it.

Comment: Did you manage to get those get methods working for spark 1.6? I'm running into the same issue where I now need to do a lookup for the offset to provide as parameters in "createRDD"