# SparkStreaming: Read Kafka Stream and provide it as RDD for further processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have currently the following setup:

Application writes data to Kafka -> SparkStreaming reads the stored data (always reading from earliest entry) and does conversions to the stream -> Application needs a RDD of this result to train an mllib model.

I want to basically achieve something similar to https://github.com/keiraqz/anomaly-detection - but my data does not come from file but from kafka and needs some reprocessing in Spark to extract the training data from the input.

Reading the data and processing it in the stream is no problem. However providing it to the main Thread for further processing does not work at all.

Is there a simple way for the stream to consume data for a certain amount of time, write everything it reads in this time to some kind of data structure and afterwards using this data structure for further processing?

What I tried until now is to set a RDD outside of the stream and then use:

```
    spanDurationVectorStream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
      if(rdd.count()==0){
        flag = 1
      }
      bufferRdd.union(rdd)

     }

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(rootLoggerLevel)
    ssc.start()

    while (flag == 0) {
      Thread.sleep(1)
    }
      Thread.sleep(1)
```

However there is never something added to the bufferRdd - it remains with the single entry that I needed to initialize it.

I am running all the needed Spark Libraries on Version 2.1.1 with scala 2.11

If you need any further information I will do my best to provide you with everything you need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
A quick summary of the amazing hints of @maasg - when he gives my the possibility to accept them as an answer I will happily do that:

First: To fix the issue with RDD the code can be changed to the following:

```
spanDurationVectorStream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
      if(rdd.count()==0){
        flag = 1
      }
      bufferRdd = bufferRdd.union(rdd)

     }

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(rootLoggerLevel)
    ssc.start()

    while (flag == 0) {

    }
```

As the RDD is immutable each rdd.union will return a new RDD that has to be saved ([How history RDDs are preserved for further use in the given code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482883/how-history-rdds-are-preserved-for-further-use-in-the-given-code)). The `Thread.sleep(1)` calls are simply unnecessary. With this setup I am able to use the RDD to train the model.

However @maasg added that he would recommend for the training scenario to not use Spark Streaming but basic Spark as described in [Read Kafka topic in a Spark batch job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026627/read-kafka-topic-in-a-spark-batch-job)

The only piece that remains unclear to me as of now is how to efficiently get the earliest and latest offset to receive the full content that is stored in Kafka at the moment of execution.

Comment: Why are you not simply processing your data inside your foreachRDD ? Do you realy need an union of all rdd ?

Comment: I need the data to train a machine learning model - for e.g. normalization I need an overview about the toal of what I have.

Comment: What I basically want to achieve is something similar to https://github.com/keiraqz/anomaly-detection with the difference that I get my training data and the data to predict on from kafka.

Comment: To build your training dataset you can save rdd to csv files then use all this files to train your model.

Comment: Would this work in a distributed environment? And if yes how? I tried to work with bufferedWriters and rdd.saveAsTextFile but could not figure out how to set them up properly to later collect all the generated text files

Comment: How much data do you need to keep to train your model?

Comment: the issue with your buffer RDD is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482883/how-history-rdds-are-preserved-for-further-use-in-the-given-code   But in this case there might be better solutions. See previous comment/question.

Comment: I also don't understand what's the intention with the `Thread.sleep`. Could you comment on that?

Comment: @maasg As I am currently just evaluating for a demo scenario it is not clearly specified how big that dataset will be. But the more data I am able to handle effieciently the better. The Thread.sleep was just something I tried as I assumed I might be to fast to access the rdd - however your link solved that issue. If you could write this as an answer and maybe add your opinion on how to work efficiently with a large input set, I will happily accept this as the answer.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of 'how fresh' should the data be.  We could keep `n` historical periods in a window. So at each interval, we could train the model on the last `n` intervals and score the new data with that model (I think that's the intention, right?).  Each new interval also becomes part of the history and older intervals are dropped in a rolling-window fashion.

Comment: @maasg this sounds interesting - currently I was just thinking about just fetching everything that is in the kafka queue when I start the application to initially train the model or decide to do an update on the model. So basically kafka decides about the amount of available data. It might even be enough to just close the streaming context afterwards - however I have not managed to do so yet - but this is something not related to this question.

Comment: that sounds more like a batch process. You might not need the complexity of a streaming job to do that. If your model does not change after training it with the kafka data the 1st time, I'd try vainilla Spark instead.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026627/read-kafka-topic-in-a-spark-batch-job

Comment: @maasg just another amazing point you make - I did not realize there was a batch way to access the data. As the model cannot handle streaming data anyway and needs to be retrained completly if I am not mistaken I could always run a batch process to do so with a lot less of the hassle I have right now - operations to RDDs and Streams in regards of mapping, filtering and there like are identical, aren't they?

Comment: @maasg I am just trying to figure out how to derive the required offsets for the KafkaUtils.createRDD call. The KafkaCluster class, as mentioned in the linked question, seems not to be available in my project. Do you have some more hints for me as Spark/Kafka newbie?