# Spark - Get earliest and latest offset of Kafka without opening stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am currently using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` to connect my spark application with the kafka queue. For Streams everything works fine. For a specific scenario however I just need the whole content of the kafka queue exactly once - for this I got the suggestion to better use `KafkaUtils.createRDD` ([SparkStreaming: Read Kafka Stream and provide it as RDD for further processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625956/sparkstreaming-read-kafka-stream-and-provide-it-as-rdd-for-further-processing))

However for `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` I cannot figure out how to get the earliest and latest offset for my Kafka topic that would be needed to create the Offset-Range I have to hand of the the `createRDD` method.

What is the recommended way to get those offsets without opening a stream? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you need to generate a single batch from Kafka, why use spark streaming?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I need spark streaming for several other usecases in my applications. So I thought I would use its API for receiving a single RDD as well. What is your suggested way to achieve what I want to do? If it is better practice to use another way to connect to Kafka I am happy to do it another way.

Comment: You can run a batch job which manually connects to Kafka using the it's driver, and if you want the data to be computed using your distributed cluster, you can wrap it in an `RDD` using `SparkContext.parallelize`

Comment: When I search for connecting spark with kafka I get only results for streaming-kafka - @YuvalItzchakov do you have any hint where to look for your suggested driver approach? Even though I assume that there has to be some way with streaming-kafka as it is suggested so frequently.

Comment: I'm really interested in solution for this issue. Unfortunately the one answer given by @rukavitsya describes solution for different problem.

Comment: @marcin I just had a conversation with an experienced Spark Streaming developer. He told me that the best bet is to open the Streaming and close it right after. He said he did manage to get the batch access working, but it does not yield an benefit. Maybe this setup suggested in another question I posted is of some use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117513/opening-two-kafkastreams-after-each-other-with-different-streamingcontext

Answer (score 0):

After reading several discussions I am able to get the earliest or latest offset from a specific partition with :

```
val consumer = new SimpleConsumer(host,port,timeout,bufferSize,"offsetfetcher");
val topicAndPartition = new TopicAndPartition(topic, initialPartition)
val request = OffsetRequest(Map(topicAndPartition -> PartitionOffsetRequestInfo(OffsetRequest.EarliestTime,1)))
val offsets = consumer.getOffsetsBefore(request).partitionErrorAndOffsets(topicAndPartition).offsets

return offsets.head
```

but still , how to replicate the behaviour of "from_beginning" in a kafka_consumer.sh CLI command is something I do not know by the KafkaUtils.createRDD aproach.

Comment: You can open `kafka_consumer.sh `, inspect that it's just shelling out to a Java class, and go look at Kafka source code :)

Comment: that is true ! I've done that and it helps in deed !