# Opening two KafkaStreams after each other with different StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am currently trying to implement a two staged process in spark streaming. First I open a kafkaStream, read everything that is already in the topic by using `auto.offset.reset=earliest` and train my model on it.
I use a stream for that as I could not find out how to do it without opening a stream before ([Spark - Get earliest and latest offset of Kafka without opening stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755649/spark-get-earliest-and-latest-offset-of-kafka-without-opening-stream)).
As I have not discovered a way to stop the streams without stopping the whole StreamingContext I stop the context after model calculation with `ssc.stop(true, true)`.

When I now try to create a new StreamingContext (using either the old sparkConfig or a new one with the same parameters), call my method to open a new KafkaStream with new groupId and `auto.offset.reset=latest` it looks like there is no streaming happening at all when I write new content to the Kafka topic. Neither print() nor count() nor println in forEachRDD are resulting in any output in my IDE.

The structure of the application looks like:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(sparkAppName).setMaster(sparkMaster)
      .set("spark.local.dir", sparkLocalDir)
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

    sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Span]))
    sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Spans]))
    sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]))

    val trainingSsc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(batchInterval))
    trainingSsc.checkpoint(checkpoint)
    //val predictor = (model, ninetynine, median, avg, max)
    val result = trainKMeans(trainingSsc);

    trainingSsc.stop(true, false)

    val predictionSsc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(batchInterval))
    val threshold = result._5
    val model = result._1

    kMeansAnomalyDetection(predictionSsc, model, threshold)  
}
```

I hope you can point me to the mistake I made - and if you need further details just let me know. Any help and hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the program looks like it's going in the right direction but there are few points that need fixing:

Spark Streaming will start the streaming scheduler when the `streamingContext.start()` is issued. DStream operations will only be executed by the scheduler. This means that sequencing these two calls will no bear any results:

```
val result = trainKMeans(trainingSsc);
trainingSsc.stop(true, false)
```

The streaming context will be stopped before any training could take place.

Instead, we should do this:

```
val result = trainKMeans(trainingSsc)
trainingSsc.foreachRDD{_ => trainingSsc.stop(false, false) } // note that we don't stop the spark context here
trainingSsc.start()
trainingSsc.awaitTermination()
```

In this case, we start the streaming process; we let the first interval execute, in which our model will be trained, and then we stop the processing.

The second stream should be started on a different group than the first one (kafka stream creation is not shown in the code snippet)

For the second streaming context, we are missing a start:

```
val predictionSsc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(batchInterval)) // note that we pass a sparkContext here, not a config. We reuse the same spark context.
val threshold = result._5
val model = result._1
kMeansAnomalyDetection(predictionSsc, model, threshold) 
predictionSsc.start()
predictionSsc.awaitTermination()
```

We should have a working stream at this point.

Comment: I really forgot to add the predictions.start() - that's why the prediction did not start. I will evaluate whether it is possible to put the start of the training inside the main method as well - however as I need some processing of the extracted RDD after the context has stopped I am not quite sure how I can achieve that. But your recommendation looks like a perfectly structure I should aim to achieve.