# Read from kafka in a Spark batch job (fromOffset untilOffset)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I saw on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026627/read-kafka-topic-in-a-spark-batch-job) that we can read messages from Kafka in spark batch jobs using `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils#createRDD` but this method requires a offset range that needs a 'from offset' and 'until offset'. I'm getting the 'from offset' from `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster#getLatestLeaderOffsets` method but how can I get the until offset? I'm using `kafka-2.1.1-0.9.0.1`

Comment: The latest offset should ideally be the "until offset", otherwise, there is nothing to go "until"

Comment: Anyway, if you use the same consumer group for each batch, then your offsets would be maintained internally by Kafka. You just set the starting offset to the earliest, then you chose how many messages to consume, and when to commit the offset. Note: I'm talking about the regular Kafka API, not Spark

Comment: The latest offset is the offset of the next message to read. It returns the same offset stored in Zookeeper. That is why I'm using it in the begining. The earliest offset is returning aways 0. In the end of the my processing I save the until offset in kafka (and Zookeeper).

Comment: The problem of chosing a number of messages to read is that we can get a offset out of range by not knowing how many messages are in kafka. And sometimes we read less messages than we want.

Comment: You can still `poll()` in a while loop. In a compacted topic, or if the topic has not reached the retention period, the earliest offset of the topic may be 0, but you need to get the offset for your application's consumer group to "resume consumption"

Comment: You were right. Latest offset should be used for the "until offset". I'm getting the "from offset" using the `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster#getConsumerOffsets` method passing the consumer group id. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetOffsetShell to fetch latest offset from any topic

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic myTopic --time -1
```

this will return :

```
myTopic:12341:47841
```

which mean 47841 is the latest offset for topic **myTopic**