# Consume kafka data to HDFS Spark Batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs

I have a lot of Kafka topics with 1 partition each, being produced and consumed to/from (REST API - Kafka - SQL server).
But now I want to take periodic dumps of this data to keep in HDFS to perform analytics on later down the line.

Since this basically is just a dump I need, I'm not sure that I need spark streaming. 
However all documentation and examples use Spark streaming for this.

Is there a way to populate a DF/RDD from a Kafka topic without having a streaming job running? Or is the paradigm here to kill the "streaming" job once the set window of min-to-max offset have been processed?
And thus treating the streaming job as a batch job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly identified, you do not have to use Spark Streaming for this. One approach would be to use the HDFS connector for Kafka Connect. Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. It takes a Kafka topic and writes messages from it to HDFS. You can see the documentation for it [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs).

Comment: as far as I know it's not part of Kafka, only part of confluent's distro of kafka, or am I missing something?

Comment: Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka.

Comment: The HDFS connector is open source, and available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createRDD` method of `KafkaUtils` to have spark batch job.

Similar question has been answered here- 
[Read Kafka topic in a Spark batch job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026627/read-kafka-topic-in-a-spark-batch-job)

Comment: that seems to be correct, however It seems I'm now in charge of keeping track of the offset myself, but the "KafkaCluster.getLatestLeaderOffsets" don't seem to work in spark 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is a stream processing platform, so using with spark streaming is easy.

You could use Spark streaming and then check point the data at specified intervals, which fulfills your requirement.

For more on check pointing : - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing

Comment: True, but I don't want an application to be claiming resources 24/7 when it's not required. Since I need to scale this out, having 300+ semi-idle spark jobs running is just a bit overkill. Also, in a multi-tenant cluster this is a sure way to lose friends ;)

Comment: Else you will have to kill your job once your check pointing is done.